# Convert string to array in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

i am trying to input array in robot framework but it is taken as a single string. How to convert it to array?

```
*** Variables ***  
${SOFT}=   4790707-00    4778582  
${SUFFIX}   VD  
${LOCATION}   1  
${ECMCOUNT}    1
```

I declared variables as above but ${SOFT} is taken as single string rather than list

Comment: are you expecting it to be an array with two values?

Answer (score 1):

Use `@` when defining an array:

```
*** Variables ***
@{SOFT}=  4790707-00    4778582 

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    length should be  ${SOFT}  2
```

For more information see the section [Creating Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-variables) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: I created list  @{MY_SIMPLE_LIST}=  Create List   Star Trek   Star Wars, but when i pass this to method in different directory Create list is also getting icluded in list. how can i avoid that?

Comment: @user3443200: I do not know what your comment means. Yes, you can use `Create List` to create a list if you don't want to create it in the `*** Variables ***` section. Your question was about how to do it in the `*** Variables ***` section.

Comment: I created list @{MY_SIMPLE_LIST}= Create List Star Trek Star Wars, but when i pass this to method in different directory "Create list" is also getting included in list. how can i avoid that?

Comment: @user3443200: you can't include `Create List` in the `*** Variables ***` section. You can only put names and values, you can't call keywords.